CMake use relative path for source files
I have a CMake project on my host, and build it in a docker container. The paths of the files on the host are not the same as in the docker container.
CMake produces absolute paths, and pass them to the compiler.
As a result, the compiler output refers to file with paths from the docker container. This breaks my ability to directly jump to a source file, on the host, from an error message.
My goal is to make the paths I get in gcc errors to be relative to the project root, so that jumping to the error in the source from my editor is easy.
To clarify:

my project file with error, on host, is ~/src/mcu/app/myfile.c
the compiler output refers to that file like this: /src/app/myfile.c (the location in the container)
the CMake generated makefile refers to the source with absolute path. In build.make: gcc [...] -c /src/app/myfile.c. Making these absolute paths is what I think I should try to fix.

I have seen this, but it seems really hacky and complicated. Also CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS, but it does not seem to do anything (as warned in the doc). Surely I cannot be alone with that use case?
I have also tried this:
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/app/myfile.c
)

with no success.
How do I force CMake to use relative paths for source files?

"I have seen this, but it seems really hacky and complicated... Surely I cannot be alone with that use case?" - Eh? You point to the question about the same problem, and then tell that you along with the use case?
